# Javascript, -100% of viewport not pixel

Tags: javascript, html, css

My problem is simple, but I can't seem to figure it out! My javascript should not deduct 100 pixels, i want 100% of viewport!

```
smoothScrollTo(document.getElementById('bottom').offsetTop - 100)
```

should look like:

```
smoothScrollTo(document.getElementById('bottom').offsetTop - '100%')
```

but for some reason this is not working.

The answer must be in Javascript (cannot use jQuery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
smoothScrollTo(document.getElementById('bottom').offsetTop - viewportHeight )
```